# perl + append WORD in the end of the last line in the file

Tags: perl

I use the following perl one line in order to append WORD in the end of the last line in the file

```
     perl -p -i -e 's/$/WORD/;' file
```

But it's append the WORD in every line -

How to fix the perl syntax in order to append the WORD only on the last line in the file

example

```
  more file

  AAAAA BBB
  WWWWW
  EEEEE WORD
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to detect that you''ve hit the end-of-file using [eof](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/eof.html):

```
perl -p -i -e 'eof && s/$/WORD/;'  file
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's an equivalent using `sed`:

```
sed -ie '$s/$/WORD/' file
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add the `-0` flag:

```
perl -0pie 's/$/WORD/' file
```

I'd never use `-i` without an added extension by the way.
If your Perl doesn't do what you intended, your input will be lost.
By the way, `;` is not a statement terminator in Perl, but a statement separator.

```
perl -i.orig -0pe 's/$/WORD/' file
```

Another handy idiom, for testing:

```
perl -0pe 's/$/WORD/' file | diff file -
```